# Why does <a> tag with helper not show as hyperlink in .net core3.0?

Tags: razor, anchor, asp.net-core-3.1, tag-helpers

I've used these tag helpers in other other projects without issue but in my current project, the browser doesn't recognise them as a URL. The href tag works as expected, the issue is just when using the tag helper.

```
<a href="/MyController/MyAction">MyLink </a> // Works fine as expected.


<a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction">MyLink </a> //Does not appear as URL
```

The browser just renders the html as this:

```
   <a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction">MyLink </a>
```

Suggesting the tag helpers are not recognised.

Is there a reason that tag helper might get deactivated or turned off by mistake?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was caused by my _ViewImports.cshtml file going missing.
Not sure how that happened but it was easy to fix.

Right click on Views folder -> Add new item.
Choose "Razor views imports"

In the new file, add the single line of code:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

It should now work.